# Dynamically remove dropdown option from SharePoint form

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, dropdown, getelementbyid

I'm trying to remove multiple dropdown options from my SharePoint 2007 list, based on the selection of a previous dropdown. I already have Javascript running on the page, so a Javascript/jQuery solution would be ideal. I've read getElementByID can be used to get the specific field I need to remove an option from, and .remove can remove the value, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. For SharePoint, what field name should I be using in getElementByID()? Is there a better solution to this?